# Kotlin, incorrect Elvis statement is called when performing nested nullability check

Tags: kotlin

I found that in the case below the Elvis block **is** getting called
when in fact it refers to the outer nullability check

```
val outer : String? = ""
val inner : String? = null

outer?.let {
    inner?.let {
        // do something
    }
} ?: System.out.println("Outer else")
```

> Outer else

Adding an Elvis branch to the inner nullability check behaves as expected:

```
outer?.let {
    inner?.let {
        // do something
    } ?: System.out.println("Inner else")
} ?: System.out.println("Outer else")
```

> Inner else

Is it a Kotlin bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code behaves as expected. The left hand operand of the `?:` operator in your case is

```
outer?.let {
    inner?.let {
        // do something
    }
}
```

`outer` is not null, so the outer `let` block will be executed. `inner` is null, hence the second `let` will not be called and the return value of the outer block will be null. This makes the entire expression evaluate to null, therefore the right-hand operand of the `?:` operator gets executed.

In your second example, the value of the outer block is calculated as

```
inner?.let {
    // do something
} ?: System.out.println("Inner else")
```

Since `inner` is null the right-hand operand of the `?:` will get called and will evaluate to `Unit`, and that is the value of the outer block.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a kotlin bug. `a?.let { expr }` evaluates to null if

1. a is null, or
2. expr evaluates to null

Piecing things together, your whole expression is evaluated as follows:

11. `inner?.let { expr }` evaluates to null, because `inner` is null (case 1 above)
12. so `outer?.let { ... }` evaluates to null (case 2 above), because what's inside the braces evaluates to null (bullet 11.)
13. So, since what's left of the `?:` operator is null (bullet 12.), the outer elvis expression is evaluated.

When you add an elvis after `inner?.let { }`, the `outer?.let { }` doesn't return null anymore, it returns `Unit`, so the outer elvis is not evaluated. Is that clear?

Answer (score 2):

The Elvis operator is not just for nullability checks, it will also evaluate the result of the statement and if `null` it'll will run the second condition.

In other words, if `inner?.let{}` evaluates to `null` (if `inner` is null or the `let` block returns null), you'll get the print `Outer else`.

Adding the Elvis operator to the inner block further confirms this, since it seems that something in that expression evaluates to null.